# How to add an ecommerce?

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, e-commerce

I have a simple web where the most complex thing is a contact form. I need to add an ecommerce now and I have 0 experience with this.

Do you know a web or a place where I could learn how to do this and make payments safe? Is it very complex? Is there some kind of library or api where I could use for this?

I am working with Vue and I have another website with the same problem made with Angular.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

it's possible to create a safety payments on your website but if you don't have user space, there is a lot of work (resgister, order, payments...). What back end techno use you ? (PHP, node.js, ...)

In the second time what method payement do you want to use ? A basic request on google can help you for paypal integration [paypal integration nodejs](https://www.nodejsera.com/paypal-payment-integration-using-nodejs-part1.html)

Finally, if you don't have time you can use a open-source e-commerce solution as : [prestashop](https://www.prestashop.com/)

Comment: Nodejs. What do you mean with "second time"? I want to use paypal, google, and the most common methods.

Comment: Do you know of a tutorial to build a safe payment (the first you mentioned)?

Comment: sorry my english id vert Bad... Start by make a user space and the next step is implement payments method

Comment: Don't worry DaxBrin. Thank you for your help. Do you know a tutorial to create a payment in my own store? (Not Google or Paypal or other)